# Cascading drop down list update issues ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

I have cascading drop down lists and I want the first ddl trigger a function and load the second ddl and second ddl trigger another function and load the third ddl.

When I select the first ddl the second one loads ok but when I select the second ddl it still calls CategoryList1_SelectedIndexChanged method and they are all calling the same method.

I cannot figure out what cause this problem. I tried synch as well and it doesn't work either.

Any help will be much appreciated
Cheers

```
<ajax:UpdatePanel ID="CategoryPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="select">
    <ul>
       <li><strong>KATEGORI:</strong> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CategoryList1" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="CategoryList1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </li>
        <li><strong>MARKA:</strong> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CategoryList2" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="CategoryList2_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </li>
        <li><strong>MODEL:</strong>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CategoryList3" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="CategoryList3_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </li>
        <li class="button"><asp:Button ID="GoButton" OnClick="GoButton_Click" Text="" runat="server" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>

     <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CategoryList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CategoryList2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CategoryList3" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</ajax:UpdatePanel>
```